# post request using retrofit custom parser

Tags: android, http, post, retrofit

Guуs, can you help me with retrofit. I'm trying to implement Post request, but i don't know how to do it right.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/tools/")
    SaleEvent updateUser(@Field("field1") String field1, @Field("field2") String field2);
```

Class SaleEvent has the same fields as json objects in JsonArray "updates" 
The problem is - i have complicated response not easy to parse for gson:

```
{
  "tag": "check_update",
  "success": 1,
  "error": 0,
  "updates": [
    {
      "uid": "47",
      "shop_name": "Ashan",
      "shop_address": "\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u043f\u0435\u043a\u0442 25",
      "name": "\u0410\u0448\u0430\u043d",
      "vip_priority": "1",
      "event_type": "0",
      "lat": "52.4978812",
      "lon": "13.4055422",
      "image_url": "uploads\/images3.jpeg",
      "city_id": "2",
      "version": "0",
      "date_from": "2014-12-28 00:00:00",
      "date_to": "2014-12-29 00:00:00",
      "created_at": "2014-07-10 00:00:00",
      "updated_at": "2014-07-10 00:00:00",
      "comment_long": "ewrterwt",
      "comment_short": "wertewrt"
    },
    {
      "uid": "48",
      "shop_name": "Kvadrat",
      "shop_address": "\u0432\u0443\u043b. \u0414\u0438\u043c\u0438\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430, 7",
      "name": "\u041a\u0432\u0430\u0434\u0440\u0430\u0442",
      "vip_priority": "1",
      "event_type": "0",
      "lat": "52.7678812",
      "lon": "13.3855422",
      "image_url": "/uploads\/images1.jpeg",
      "city_id": "2",
      "version": "0",
      "date_from": "2014-12-28 00:00:00",
      "date_to": "2014-12-29 00:00:00",
      "created_at": "2014-07-10 00:00:00",
      "updated_at": "2014-07-10 00:00:00",
      "comment_long": "ewrtwret",
      "comment_short": "Privet"
    },

  ]
}
```

What i need is to get response in ArrayList

```
@FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/tools/")
        ArrayList<SaleEvent> updateUser(@Field("field1") String field1, @Field("field2") String field2);
```

Smth like this

Problem solved:
The problem was in using ArrayList instead of List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the data from ur complex JSON by using TypeAdapterFactory.
Here is a simple implementation of the class
**ItemTypeAdapterFactory.java**

```
public class ItemTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

                JsonElement jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(in);
                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    if (jsonObject.has("updates") && jsonObject.get("updates").isJsonObject())
                    {
                        jsonElement = jsonObject.get("updates");
                    }
                }

                return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
            }
        }.nullSafe();
    }
}
```

Then you need to create a GSON Builder.Here is a sample of it.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ItemTypeAdapterFactory()) // This is the important line ;)
                .create();
```

Finally Attach the GSON Builder to the RequestAdapter as:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .build();
```

Now You have to declare the GSON response object and the request parameters:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/tools/")
    private Void updateUser(@Field("field1") String field1, @Field("field2") String field2,Callback<JSONResponse> fbLogin);
```

Here is a **JSONResponse.java**

```
class JSONResponse {
@SerializedName("update")
ArrayList<SaleEvent> array;
}
```

Then declare **SaleEvent.java**

```
class SaleEvent {
@SerializedName("uid")
int uid;
@SerializedName("shop_name")
String uid;
@SerializedName("version")
int version;
....
}
```

Then strt the request... Hope everything will work fine

This will work out for u

Comment: Gowtham Raj, it's not working because this adapter is only for jsonObject, but not for JsonArray

Comment: ok. i made it to work. the problem was in converting from json Date. I excluded date and it worked